# useGoogleMap inside Next JS

Tags: next.js, react-hooks, react-google-maps-api

Does anyone use useGoogleMap() inside NEXT JS component? It gives `Unhandled Runtime Error Invariant Violation: useGoogleMap needs a GoogleMap available up in the tree` error. I just need to refer to map of google Map inside Next JS.

Comment: did you wrap the component that are use this hook by `GoogleMap`

Comment: what do you mean to wrap it? it is a hook! example: https://unpkg.com/browse/@react-google-maps/api@1.8.1/src/useGoogleMap.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to wrap the component that are using this hook by GoogleMap component
as the [documentation](https://react-google-maps-api-docs.netlify.app/#map-instance) say:

> The GoogleMap component uses React Context internally to pass the map instance around. For the convenience the value is exposed with hook useGoogleMap (requires React 16.8+).